# Is there a dataset that contains two or more doctors prescribing two or more medicine doses in continuous value to patients and report their condition

Tags: evaluation, continuous, bandit

I'm currently working on the problem of evaluating a contextual bandit (target) policy given a dataset that is generated by another policy (which is off-policy policy evaluation for contextual bandits)

The problem I tackle has two or more continuous action dimensions.
And I need real-world dataset that satisfies this condition.
If there is a medical dataset that suits this condition, I think it best suits me.

Is there a dataset that contains two or more doctors (corresponding to 2 policies)
prescribing two or more medicine doses in continuous value (which corresponds to 2 or more continuous action dimensions) to patients and also contains the patients' condition after taking the medicine (which corresponds to rewards)?